# How to resolve PHP PHP_EOL issue

Tags: php

the constant:

> PHP_EOL

is supposed to represent a line break on both windows and linux, however when I run on my linux box there is no spacing (has caused major headaches generating .txt files that now have boxes instead of line breaks).

Any quick fix to the issue?

### EDIT

It seems the common answer is that anything created on the Linux machine will not 'appear' correctly within notepad. Is there any to correct this on the back end within notepad itself(a find and replace per say and replace with an actual break?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some "fixes":

1. Use `\r\n` for your line breaks to make Windows happy.
2. Don't use notepad.

`PHP_EOL` only represents something per the system it's running on. It cannot possibly simultaneously represent every EOL sequence that each OS uses.

Comment: konforce - no need for the \r\n on windows as the above works fine (find and replace is of course possible here but based on my knowledge, this should work regardless)

Comment: If you create a file on Windows using `PHP_EOL` it will look fine in Notepad. If you create that same file on Linux using `PHP_EOL` it will not work on Notepad. In what case are you having a problem?

Comment: @konforce - thanks for the suggestion on Notepad, viewing in word or even WordPad generates desired results. Any chance the line break (not showing in notepad) would actually be an issue?

Comment: of note: even when echoing to a screen output (html) shouldn't the PHP_EOL create a break in the text on the screen?

Comment: @JM4, Notepad only knows about "\r\n". So really the only solution is to not use Notepad or to use what it wants. Linux programs are typically smarter and will know how to parse "\r\n" even though they really just want "\n". The best solution depends on who these files are for, etc. `PHP_EOL` will not create a break in HTML (only the BR or similar tag will) and if you "view source" you will have the same problem if Notepad is the editor of choice.

Comment: added edit but anyway to resolve within notepad after the fact?

Comment: @JM4, You can support Notepad directly by using `\r\n` when echoing out the content. I don't think Notepad has the capacity to search and replace on special characters. However, I believe both Word and Wordpad (write) will convert the line endings to `\r\n` after saving, so that's another option. (Open in Wordpad, save, open in Notepad.) And if this is just for your usage, I'd highly recommend looking into a lightweight Notepad replacement that understands UNIX EOLs.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `PHP_EOL` for text-file output.

IIRC it's better to use `"\r\n"` for best compatibility.

You can `DEFINE` or `$var` it if you want.

Comment: good suggestion - went with konforce for noting that it does in fact work, just not using notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nl2br()` function:

```
echo nl2br("your first line\n your second line");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read text log file to html with line break. This works in Windows and Linux/Unix:

```
echo str_replace("\n", '<br>', file_get_contents($logfilename));
```

Comment: That does not answer the question. It's not about using HTML to display line breaks, but about reading a Unix file in Window's notepad.

Comment: Indeed, I'm sorry. But maybe it will be useful to someone how to correctly show a text file line by line in the browser, regardless of the system in which the file was created.

Comment: No harm done. You meant to be helpful, that's the spirit :)